# Play framework does not see custom http header with "_" in name

Tags: playframework

Server clients send legacy headers that look like "APP_VERSION", "PROTOCOL_VERSION" and we need to get header values, but Play framework does not see them.

For example on request

```
curl -X GET -H "APP_VERS: 1.0" "http://192.168.1.185:9000"
```

and `request().headers().containsKey("APP_VERS")`
in controller returns `false`

At the same time on request

```
curl -X GET -H "APP-VERS: 1.0" "http://192.168.1.185:9000"
```

`request().headers().containsKey("APP-VERS")`
returns `true`

Version of Play Framework is 2.3.7, running on MacOS 10.11.3. The same code running on Windows platform does see these headers.

Is there a way to get headers running server on Unix machine?